# how to change a default parameter in instantiating a python class?

Tags: python, class

I have a python class that can be instantiated in two different ways. I can either create a type1 class or type2 class.... But how could I change only one particular default during instantiation?

```
class MyClass:
    DEFAULT_PARAMS = {
        "type_1": {
            "name": "smith",  # Stock name
            "region": "newman",
            "country": "USA"
        },
        "type_2": {
            "age": "34", # Stock name
            "gender": "male",
            "income": "100":
        }
    }

m = MyClass("type_1")
m = MyClass("type_2")
```

Let's say I want to create a class of type_1, but I want to change the country to (e.g. CANADA).... What is the proper syntax for that?

Comment: I would create two different classes with different parameters in `__init__` like `__init__(self, country="USA", ...)` and then you can use `MyClassType1(country="Canada")`

Comment: please rethink your abstractions, what you ask for is possible, but has a bad code smell, eg likely to violate SOLID principles

Comment: In what context do classes with such different attributes should share a common type?

Answer (score 0):

If both `type_1` and `type_2` must belong to the same class, it looks like this is a good use case for [class inheritance](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance):

```
class MyClass:
   pass

class Type1(MyClass):
   def __init__(self, name="smith", region="newman", country="USA"):
       self.name = name
       self.region = region
       self.country = country

class Type2(MyClass):
   def __init__(self, age="34", gender="male", income="100"):
       self.age = age
       self.gender = gender
       self.income = income
```

You can override default attributes like such:

```
x = Type1(country="CANADA")
```

In this scenario, instances of `Type1` and `Type2` are also instances of `MyClass`:

```
x = Type1(country="CANADA")
print(isinstance(x, MyClass)) # True

y = Type2()
print(isinstance(y, MyClass)) # True
```

---

Also, this is just my opinion, but I find it weird that `age` and `income` are set to strings. Maybe they should be numbers instead?

```
class Type2(MyClass):
   def __init__(self, age=34, gender="male", income=100):
       self.age = age
       self.gender = gender
       self.income = income
```